# How to config lombok on JBoss Developer Studio 7 and Mac OS X?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, jboss, lombok

I installed JBoss Developer Studio 7 in my MacBook with Mac Os X Snow Leopard.

I want to use Lombok and i try to configure into "jbdevstudio.ini" file (or eclipse.ini) but I can't locate it.

I have this file in JBoss Developer Studio 7 on Windows 7... but i haven't it on Mac Os X.

Where is the .ini file placed?
Where is the place in JBoss Developer Studio 7 to config Memory space, virtual machine arguments, eclipse configuration... etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution... The File jbdevstudio.ini is into:
$PATH_TO_JBDS/studio/JBoss Developer Studio.app/Contents/MacOs

Note: You only need to do secondary click over "JBoss Developer Studio.app" and click "Show package contents" to show package contents and navigate /Contents/MacOs

To config lombok only need 2 things:

1- File lombok.jar into JBoss Developer Studio PATH: $PATH_TO_JBDS/studio/lombok.jar

2- Put into jbdevstudio.ini :

```
-Xbootclasspath/a:$PATH_TO_JBDS/studio/lombok.jar
-javaagent:$PATH_TO_JBDS/studio/lombok.jar
```

Comment: Yup, that's where its hidden on macs :)

Sounds like we should add detecting JBoss Studio Developer to the installer; we already added STS which is an eclipse variant.

Is JBoss Developer Studio 7 also an eclipse offshoot?

Comment: Yes rzwitserloot, **JBoss Developer Studio 7** is an eclipse offshoot... and **lombok installer** is working perfectly to detect this IDE on _Windows 7_, but it doesn't works on _Mac Os X_. :|